# TomEE lookup errors

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jndi, openejb, apache-tomee

I've a WebApp that uses tomcat and openejb in separate installations. I'm trying to move this to a TomEE (web profile / plus) environment and I'm running into lookup errors. JNDIContext is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException.

I tried w/ TomEE web profile first. My webapp also uses web services and google search lead me to try TomEE plus because the web profile doesn't support web services. No luck w/ this version either.

One difference between the two version is that in the TomEE web profile, I see all the Remote objects when I access the openejb webapp. However I don't see them w/ TomEE plus version.

http://localhost:8080/openejb/viewjndi.jsp

Any suggestions of how I could resolve this? I'm guessing it is configuration issue and I don't know which one.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.createBusinessObject(JNDIContext.java:203)
    org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:247)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    org.bluebox.customer.client.CustomerConnection.getCustomerAccountRemote(CustomerConnection.java:67)
    org.bluebox.customer.client.CustomerLogin.prepare(CustomerLogin.java:65)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

Answer (score 2):

TomEE Plus is definitely the right distro to use if migrating from an OpenEJB/Tomcat install.  They match identically in features with the difference that the stack now supports full EJB 3.1, JAP 2.0 and JAX-RS.  The Web Profile version of TomEE is quite a bit leaner and lacks WebServices, JMS and any non-WebProfile requirement.  Here's a brief [comparison of APIs supported](http://openejb.apache.org/comparison.html).

That looks like a bug that was fixed with TomEE 1.0.0-beta-2 released in January.  If you can give it a try, it'd be wonderful.  We will absolutely want to make sure any issues you might face are cleared up before the 1.0.0 GA.